# Callback function for "contentUpdated" event in JS

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript

In Magento 2 we are executing `data-mage-init` and `x-magento-init` in dynamic content (ajax response) using using `contentUpdated`:

```
<script type=“text/x-magento-init”>
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>

container.trigger('contentUpdated')
```

I need trigger another callback function after `contentUpdated` event. Anybody know any **callback method** for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not want to use a standard event?

```
container.on(
    'contentUpdated',
    yourCallbackFunctionGoesHere()
);

container.trigger('contentUpdated');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I already tried but not working. I need to change options of a plugin which was executed in contentUpdated event.

Comment: @AnjithKP Could you be more specific, what exactly do you want to change and where?

Comment: I need to open some items in accordion after ajax call is made. When I tried that above, its showing that you can not use the accordion plugin before initializing.